# Why getItem(position) should be casted inside a generic class (i.e. Custom ArrayAdapter<T>)?

Tags: java, android, generics, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to understand generics in Java. I'm working in Android studio. I have a `Word` class and I have an `ArrayList` of `Word` objects.

```
ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried to make a generic class like this

```
public class wordAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    public wordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> object) {
        super(context, 0, object);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Word wordItem = getItem(position); 
        // This line gives an error because it needs to be casted to "Word"
        // Rest of the code
    }
}
```

Now, my question is why the compiler complaining? When I use this class I will pass an `ArrayList` containing `Word` objects. So, as far as I know the following line of code:

```
wordAdapter<Word> adapter = new wordAdapter<>(this, words);
```

Should transfer the type parameter `<T>` to be `<Word>` .
I don't get it why the compiler treats the objects obtained from `getItem(position)` as `Object` object not as `Word` objects. Plus I wonder since it is a generic, shouldn't the compiler ignore these things? How can it recognize what kind of objects I will deliver?

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. Classes go UpperCase. Then: enhance your question to be a real [mcve]. Dont post only half of the code.

Comment: `getItem` returns a `T` in all cases, but `T` isn't always `Word`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If defined like this

```
public class MyClass<T> extends SomeClass<T>{

  public T someMethod(){
     // T could be any type. Could be Word, could be String, ......
     T someObject = super.getItem();
     return someObject
  }

}
```

T is an undefined type inside the class `MyClass` because it is defined generic. Later on any type could be passed.

```
MyClass<Word> instance1 = new MyClass<Word>();
MyClass<String> instance2 = new MyClass<String>();

Word value1 = instance1.someMethod();
String value2 = instance2.someMethod();
```

So while operating inside `MyClass` you don't know what type will be defined later on.

What you need to do is to define the type inside your class to be able to use it. So instead of passing the generic type later on from the outside, you define it already on the inside

```
public class WordClass extends SomeClass<Word>{

  public Word someMethod(){
    // since the generic type is now defined as Word, you can reference it as such
    Word wordObject = super.getItem();
    return wordObject;
  }

}
```

Since in your case the type is unknown but you are trying to define it as Word, you need to add a so called cast. In other words telling java to look at the returned unknown type as a object of the word type. If you only use your class for Word it would work but is ugly and unnecessary. But if you would use it later for lets say Strings it would break since a String object can't be casted to a word object

**EDIT**:
I just read in one of your comments that you would like to create a generic class for all kind of datatypes which can use the type-specific functions.

Well technically this is possible by doing type-checks and then cast them. But this would be very very ugly.

```
public class UglyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{

  public void doTypeSpecificStuff(T obj){
    Class<T> objectClass = obj.getClass();
    if(objectClass.equals(Integer.class)){
      Integer intObj = (Integer) obj;
      // here you can call Integer-specific methods
    }else if(objectClass.equals(String.class)){
      String strObj = (String) obj;
      // here you can call String-specific methods
    }
    else if(objectClass.equals(Word.class)){
      Word wordObj = (Word) obj;
      // here you can call Word-specific methods
    }
    else{
      // object is unsupported type. Throw exception or do whatever
    }
  }

}
```

However the usual way to go about this kind of stuff is to create one adapter for each type you need to support. Doing it this way is very ugly and shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: Great! can you please answer this question:
All the methods inside the `ArrayAdapter` class don't perform any operations that is type-specific .Is this Right? 
If Not! why can't I make a generic class that looks like the `ArrayAdapter` in this sense. Thanks

Comment: @haythemkamal You can create generic types that extend certain other types. public class SomeClass<T extends Word>. This way T always has to be either Word or a subclass of it. Then you can call type specific functions of T even from within the generic class. Later on when defining T you have to pass either Word or a subclass of it. You wouldn't be able to insert types like Integer or String anymore since they don't extend Word. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @haythemkamal look at the edit-part of my answer. i updated it to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I know doing this is ugly but I just was trying to deeply understand generics.Your marvelous answer helped me a lot.

Comment: @haythemkamal casting objects to different types has nothing to do with generics. In the contrary actually. Generics was cre3ated so you can create one class handling multiple data types on a general level without having to cast arround. Also for type safety reasons. Imagine a List which is supposed to store only Strings but doesn't have generics. You can throw everything into it and once you try to access it as a string java explodes. Generics makes it secure so the casting and type checking doesn't have to be done by you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You said and I quote "without having to cast arround" and also "one class handling multiple data types" .These two sentences are so clear when we deal with `ArrayList` for example when we pass `ArrayList<String>` .I just want to know how the <E> type parameter is converted into `String` or whatever the type we pass as an argument.I want to know how this is done so I can implement it in my own generic class.Is this even possible? hope you can answer this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @haythemkamal i think you should rephrase your question or ask a new one. Continuing on a conversation in the comments is not a proper way to get information. If you ask a new one im gonna make sure to look it up and answer there. But i think you should refer to tutorials first and read articles about the matter instead of asking question right away. It seems like you are pretty new to this topic. A source i can recommend is tutorialspoint. They also have an entry for java generics

Answer (score 3):

If a `WordAdapter` is an `ArrayAdapter` that contains `Word` elements, it should be defined as:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> object) {
        super(context, 0, object);
    }

    ...
}
```

This way `getItem(position)` would return a `Word`.

Comment: Or add the bound `T extends Word`.

Comment: I get what you mean but in this case my class `WordAdapter` won't be generic.I mean what if I want the array to contain `Interger` or `String` elements.In your way, I would make three classes each extends ArrayAdapter with the corresponding type.I want a generic class to accept any data type ( which will be set when I use the class) and subsequently all corresponding methods should work if it finds the right data type.

Comment: @haythemkamal If you want the array to contain Integers or Strings, you can't expect `getItem(position)` to return a `Word` (with or without casting).

Comment: Tell if i'm wrong.All the methods inside the `ArrayAdapter` class don't perform any operations that is type-specific .Is this Right?